# How to find length of the passed array in jsrender?

Tags: arrays, jsrender

I have an array passed to jsRender like the one below:

```
var myArray = [{name: Arun},
               {name: Mohan},
               {name: Deepak}
              ]
```

Now Im passing this to the render template I have created. But inside it I need to apply a for loop for the first 2 elements of the array so that I can style it differently than the third one.
How can I find the length of the above arrray in jsrender for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From inside a `{{for someArray}}` you can get the length of the array using `{{:#get("array").data.length}}` as in:

```
{{for someArray}}
  {{:name}} (array length: {{:#get("array").data.length}}...)
{{/for}}
```

Alternatively you can pass in the array as a contextual template parameter, and use `{{:~array.length}}` as in:

```
{{for someArray ~array=someArray}}
  {{:name}} (array length: {{:~array.length}}...)
{{/for}}
```

For formatting some items in the array differently, you can simply use `{{if ...}}`, as in:

```
{{for someArray}}
  {{if #index<2}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

or you might want to look at creating a custom `{{range}}` tag or similar that iterates over a subset of indices, as in http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/tags/extend-for and http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/range.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this 
`{{for myArray ~len=myArray.length}}
    {{if #index != ~len-2}}
        <!-- Do Whatever formating you want-->
     {{/if}}
 {{/for}}`